# What's the difference between Array{Bool} and BitArray in Julia and how are they related?

Tags: arrays, boolean, julia, bitarray

I was writing a function for boolean 2d arrays:

```
function foo(A::Array{Bool,2})
   ...
end
```

Evaluating and testing it with

```
A = randbool(3,3)
foo(A)
```

returns

```
ERROR: 'foo' has no method matching foo(::BitArray{2})
```

Obviously, `randbool()` generates a `BitArray`, whereas I assumed `randbool()` would yield an `Array{Bool}`.

How are `Array{Bool}` and `BitArray` related? Why do they both exist?

Can I write `foo()` in such a way that it accept both input types using a single method (since I can't see a difference)?

Comment: Your assumption about the behavior of `randbool` isn't unreasonable — it's a pretty bad name!  It's been deprecated in 0.4 and renamed to `bitrand` (which sounds more like it'd create a BitArray). And there is a new method `rand(Bool, …)` to explicitly create an array of `Bool`. You can start using these new definitions in 0.3 with the [Compat](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl) package.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

An `Array{Bool}` stores each `true/false` value as a `Bool`, which is represented internally as a `UInt8`. So if your array has `N` elements, it will take `N` bytes to store it.

A `BitArray` stores each `true/false` value as a single bit, with (conceptually) 8 of them packed into a single `UInt8`. Consequently, it takes only `N/8` bytes to store the array. A `BitArray` also has methods defined that handle all the required bit-twiddling operations for you.

Depending on the operation, `BitArray`s are sometimes slower than the corresponding `Array{Bool}`, and sometimes faster. But by and large the performance differences are quite small, so it makes sense to use `BitArray`s unless you have a specific reason not to. But overall they are fairly interchangeable.

Note that both are subtypes of `AbstractArray{Bool}`:

```
julia> BitArray <: AbstractArray{Bool}
true

julia> Array{Bool} <: AbstractArray{Bool}
true
```

This makes it easy to write generic methods that take either one.

Comment: `AbstractArray{Bool}` is exactly the type I was looking for.