# Julia equivalent of Matlab's “logical” matrix

Tags: matrix, boolean, julia

Is there Julia equivalent for Matlab's “logical” matrix which you can use to mark certain positions in matrix and then use it for matrix manipulation?

In matlab it looks like this:

```
A=magic(3);
C=eye(size(A));
C=logical(C);
M=A;
M(C)=0;
```

I need to keep zeros on main diagonal. In matlab I would do it like this, but in Julia there is no "logical" matrix. I searched for Julia equivalent but i couldn't find anything. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [BitArray](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/arrays/#Base.BitArray) or an `Array` of `Bool`s, which are for [most intents and purposes the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623059/whats-the-difference-between-arraybool-and-bitarray-in-julia-and-how-are-they).

E.g.

```
> using LinearAlgebra

>I(3)                            # `I()` is the identity matrix function 
3×3 Diagonal{Bool,Array{Bool,1}}:
 1  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  1  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  1
```

And you can use it to zero out elements in another matrix by [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1) the logical not operator `~`, and then multiplying each element in the other matrix (by broadcasting `*` with `.*`).

For example:

```
> x = reshape(1:9,3,3)
 1  4  7
 2  5  8
 3  6  9

> x .* .~I(3)
 0  4  7
 2  0  8
 3  6  0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer! This solved my problem and I learned something new, too... I wish you all the best!

Comment: You can do it more easily than that, you could just write: `x[I(3)] .= 0`. Another way that doesn't use logical indices is with `diagind` from the LinearAlgebra stdlib: `x[diagind(x)] .= 0`.

Comment: @DNF - Thanks - for the particular example I used (`reshape(1:9,3,3)`), I would have had to `collect` the range into an array which was an extra step. But for many arrays the direct indexing would work with no extra effort needed.